# Spring, ehCache, multiple cache managers throwing errors where pre-existing caches of the same name found

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

Good evening all.. maybe someone can help me sort this out some.

I'm attempting to set up multiple cache managers, each with its own set of distinct caches.  To that end, I have the following:

MyCachingFactory:

```
public interface MyCachingFactory {
    public JCacheCacheManager cacheManager();
    public JCacheCacheManager commonCacheManager();
    public JCacheCacheManager secondaryCacheManager();
    public JCacheCacheManager secondaryCacheManager();
}
```

MyCachingFactoryImpl:

```
@EnableCaching
public class MyCachingFactoryImpl implements MyCachingFactory {
    private static final int DEFAULT_CACHE_EXPIRY = 64800;

    private static final List<String> DEFAULT_CACHES = Arrays.asList(
        "default");

    private static final List<String> COMMON_CACHES = Arrays.asList(
        "common_default", 
        "common_config", 
        "common_session",
        "common_roles", 
        "common_capabilities");

    private static final List<String> SECONDARY_CACHES = Arrays.asList(
        "secondary_default",
        "secondary_foo");

    private static final List<String> TERTIARY_CACHES = Arrays.asList(
        "tertiary_default",
        "tertiary_foo");

    @Bean  
    public JCacheCacheManager cacheManager() {
        return getNewJCacheManager(DEFAULT_CACHES);
    }

    @Bean
    public JCacheCacheManager commonCacheManager() {
        return getNewJCacheManager(COMMON_CACHES);
    }

    @Bean
    public JCacheCacheManager secondaryCacheManager() {
        return getNewJCacheManager(SECONDARY_CACHES);
    }

    @Bean
    public JCacheCacheManager tertiaryCacheManager() {
        return getNewJCacheManager(TERTIARY_CACHES);
    }

    private JCacheCacheManager getNewJCacheManager(List<String> cacheNames) {
        JCacheCacheManager springJCacheManager = new JCacheCacheManager();
        CachingProvider provider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
        EhcacheCachingProvider ehcacheProvider = (EhcacheCachingProvider) provder;
        javax.cache.CacheManager jCacheManager = ehcacheProvider.getCacheManager();

        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(1);
        cacheNames.forEach((listName) -> {
            logger.debug("[" + count + "] Creating cache name [" + listName + "].");
            jCacheManager.createCache(listName, new MutableConfiguration<>()
                .setExpiryPolicyFactory(TouchedPolicyExpiry.factoryOf(new Duration(TimeUnit.SECONDS, DEFAULT_CACHE_EXPIRY)))
                .setStoryByValue(false)
                .setStatisticsEnabled(true));

            count.incrementAndGet();
        });

        springJCacheManager.setCacheManager(jCacheManager);    

        return springJCacheManager;
    }
}
```

Example class:

```
public class Example { 
    @Resource
    private JCacheCacheManager commonCacheManager;

    @CacheResult(cacheName = "common_config")
    public String getCachedConfigByName(String name) { ... }

    @CacheResult(cacheName = "common_config") 
    public String getCachedConfigByType(String type) { ... }
}
```

However, when starting up my application, I see my debug statements for cache creation... iterating over the *same* list (in this case, COMMON_CACHE) multiple times.  This, in turn, causes a nested exception in that Spring complains that a cache named X already exists.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance  (go easy please... I am new to spring caching).

Comment: Can you put the excerpt of the log and the exception?

Comment: I see a couple of issues, but actually not the reason for the problem you are describing. E.g. `ehcacheProvider.getCacheManager()` gives you the identical `CacheManager` instance all the time. You might also like to try out [cache2k](https://cache2k.org) where I put in some effort recently to make the spring configuration quite smooth, see (cache2k - Spring Framework Integration)[https://cache2k.org/docs/latest/user-guide.html#spring]